# Avoid writing events for every child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script is managing texts where words are separated in spans, where some mouse events are going to be used. Is there a way to make it more elegant, without calling the events functions on every  tag?

```
<div id="reader">

<span id="2" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)">Hello</span>
<span id="3" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)"> </span>
<span id="4" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)">World</span>
<span id="5" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)"> </span>
<span id="6" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)">of</span>
<span id="7" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)"> </span>
<span id="8" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)">Giants</span>
<span id="9" onmousedown="pushed(this)" onmouseup="released(this)"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttons-mouse-thing').on('mousedown', function() {
       //DO the magic.
    });

    $('.buttons-mouse-thing').on('onmouseup', function() {
       //DO the magic.
    });
});
```

Or you could do this. If your functions are the same

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttons-mouse-thing').on('mousedown onmouseup', function() {
       //DO the magic.
    });
});
```

Your html:

```
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
<span id="2" class='buttons-mouse-thing'>Hello</span>
```

You can read about jQuery functionality `on` and other prototypes at its documentation https://api.jquery.com/